# Can a cognito user pool use SES with a verified domain and not a verified email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

Cognito's User Pool takes an email config that needs an ARN of a verified email. Can I use any email on a verified domain instead of a single verified email?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html
I am looking at this documentation, but I am not sure how to make a User pool with anything other than a "verified email" which is not automatable. the alternative that i would like is to automate the verification of a domain and then use any address from that that domain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We were able to accomplish this via the CLI. First, go to your verified domain in SES and add an Identity Policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "SES:SendRawEmail",
            "SES:SendEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID:identity/MYCUSTOM.DOMAIN.COM" <- arn of your SES domain
    }
  ]
}
```

Then create a json file on your local machine.

```
{
  "SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:"accountid":identity/MYCUSTOM.DOMAIN.COM",
  "ReplyToEmailAddress": "no-reply@MYCUSTOM.DOMAIN.COM",
  "EmailSendingAccount": "DEVELOPER",
  "From": "no-reply@MYCUSTOM.DOMAIN.COM"
}
```

Finally run the cli command

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id 'us-xxxx-X_XXXXXX' --region 'xx-xxxx-x' --email-configuration file://email.json
```

When this is done in the AWS console for your cognito pool you should see the ARN of the SES domain under the From email address ARN and you can specify whatever email you want in the from address field.

Note: You this is an existing pool in prod you may want to run the following command to get the email config to make sure you don't override any settings as noted in the update documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserPool.html.

```
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id 'USER_POOL_ID' --region us-east-1
```

Comment: Why does the domain in SES need a policy to send emails from its own domain? Isn't it already able to do that?

Comment: @mavann, If we do it like this it is changing **Message customization** configuration. But still in **Advanced security -> notify user -> Source ARN** it is not showing my domain ARN. What would I do to see my domain ARN in **Advanced security -> notify user -> Source ARN**?

Comment: I got the answer for my question. It is possible to set Domain ARN as a Source ARN for Advanced security by using this API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SetRiskConfiguration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_NotifyConfigurationType.html

Comment: In the policy, I had to [add AWS account for `Principal` to get it working](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-identity-owner-tasks-policy.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console):

```
    "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:root"
    },
```

Comment: For a production environment (to not lose other settings), I generated a skeleton first and update with settings `describe-user-pool

`aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --generate-cli-skeleton`

`aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --profile [PROFILE] --user-pool-id [USER_POOL] --region [REGION] --cli-input-json file://prod_settings_skeleton_based.json`

Comment: I had to follow @r.pedrosa recommendation to make this work