# Using AWS SES for custom Message in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

In Cognito there is the possibility to enter an individual sender e-mail address that uses the SES Service.

This can be done under User Pool -> General settings -> Message customizations -> From email address ARN

At this point, however, I can ONLY select an e-mail address that has been previously verified. However, I have verified the domain (created my own domain via Route 53). So I should be able to enter any e-mail address of my domain as sender.

Unfortunately, I can ONLY select e-mail addresses in the From email Address ARN selection in Cognito and not the domain ARN.

What else can I do?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645748/can-a-cognito-user-pool-use-ses-with-a-verified-domain-and-not-a-verified-email ?

Comment: No, but this seems to be a work arround. I will give it a try